# How should I store secrets for use in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-kms, google-secret-manager

If I had credentials I need to store in Google Compute Engine or Google App Engine for use at build time, how should I store them? Is there something better than storing them in code, or in a bucket?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to encrypt the secrets with a key from Cloud KMS, and store them either in a storage bucket or keep them in the binary. This lets you manage permissions and logging on the key, to indirectly manage who accesses the secret.

Comment: Any thoughts on how I should store long term access tokens that are generated by another application that my application is using? The access tokens I am getting from the other application give me complete access so I don't want to store them in plain text in my database.

Should I store an encryption key in Cloud KMS and encrypt the data in my database with that key using an NPM encryption library or should I store the access tokens directly in Cloud KMS?

Answer (score 1):

As of December 2019, you should store secrets with Google [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager):

```sh
$ echo "ABC1234..." | gcloud beta secrets create "my-api-key" \
  --data-file=- \
  --replication-policy "automatic"
```

You can use the [Secret Manager REST APIs](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/rest/) to access secrets, or a client library.