# Authenticating a google.storage.Client without saving the service account JSON to disk

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

For authentication of a Google Cloud Platform storage client, I'd like to NOT write the service account JSON (credentials file that you create) to disk. I would like to keep them purely in memory after loading them from a Hashicorp Vault keystore that is shared by all cloud instances. Is there a way to pass the JSON credentials directly, rather than passing a pathlike/file object?

I understand how to do this using a pathlike/file object as follows, but this is what I want to avoid (due to security issues, I'd prefer to never write them to disk):

```py
from google.cloud import storage

# set an environment variable that relies on a JSON file
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/service_account.json"

# create the client (assumes the environment variable is set)
client = storage.Client()

# alternately, one can create the client without the environment 
# variable, but this still relies on a JSON file.
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json("/path/to/service_account.json")
```

I have tried to get around this by referencing the JSON DATA (json_data) directly, but this throws the error: `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not dict`

```py
json_data = {....[JSON]....}
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(json_data)
```

Also, dumping to JSON, but I get the error:

`with io.open(json_credentials_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as json_fi:
OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long: '{"type": "service_account", "project_id",......`

```py
json_data = {....[JSON]....}
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(json.dumps(json_data))
```

Per the suggestion from @johnhanley, I have also tried:

```py
from google.cloud import storage
from google.oauth2 import service_account

json_data = {...data loaded from keystore...}
type(json_data)
   dict

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(json_data)
type(credentials)
   google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials

client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials)
```

This resulted in the DefaultCredentialsError:

`raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials.`

If you have ideas on how to solve this, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: 1) Where are you running this code? 2) If you do not want to store on disk, where are you storing the JSON key material? Don't trade one security hole for another. 3) To use the JSON key material use `credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(service_account_info)` and `storage.Client(credentials=credentials)` Docs: https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html and https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html

Comment: @JohnHanley, I am storing the key material in memory (after reading it from Hashicorp Vault).

Comment: @JohnHanley, I attempted what you outline above and got the following error, which seems to agree with the documentation. (This is a tightly-scoped Storage service account). Here is the error: `raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials.'

Comment: The error means you did not implement the code I suggested correctly. Refer to the documentation links I provided. Where are you running this code (a Google compute service, outside of GCP, etc).

Comment: @JohnHanley, the code is running on a local dev machine, but will eventually be running in a container on a compute-backed instance (could be any cloud).

Comment: @JohnHanley, the credentials variable is correctly typing as `google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials` and I've reviewed the docs. If you have any advice on implementation, that would be appreciated.

Comment: The error message about `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` means that the client is not finding the credentials using ADC. You need to initialize the client with credentials correctly in the line `storage.Client(credentials=credentials)`

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you loading key data with `json.loads()`? Is it a valid json?

Comment: @EmilGi, I'm building a python dict from the key value pairs I get from the Vault. It types as dict as well and the structure looks like what I would expect. I have tried using this dict in the credentials call and have also tried loads and dumps out of desperation. The contents of service_account_info are valid JSON.

Comment: What about using the [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) to store the credentials? [*Link-1*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41597874#answer-41597875), [*Link-2*](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/quickstart)

Comment: @DenisT. We are already storing the credentials/key material in Hashicorp Vault. The problem occurs when you pull the secrets out of the Vault/Secret Manager/etc. The `storage.Client` is expecting a JSON file... So, I have these secrets in memory and would like to keep them in memory rather than writing to disk.

Comment: A little late to the party but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65612814/2877256) worked for me.

Comment: The solution provided by @JohnHanley works perfectly and here is a code sample in Google Colab. I'm using the Colab secret keys to store the account info:
```from google.colab import userdata
import json
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import storage

account_info = json.loads(userdata.get('GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT'))
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(account_info)
storage_client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently there aren't built-in methods in the client library for Cloud Storage to achieve this. So here there would be 2 possibilites:

- As @JohnHanley stated use the provided built-in methods [[1]](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html)[[2]](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html) to create the constructor for the Cloud Storage client.
- You might consider as well to use another product such as [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam#runtime_service_account) or [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/access-control#apps) that would allow you to configure the authentication at the service level and avoid providing the service account credentials.

Comment: A little late to the party but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65612814/2877256) worked for me.